# lock and get next n records from table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a **oracle** table PHONE_NUMBER which has 2 columns PHONE and STATUS

```
PHONE_NUMBER 
PHONE STATUS
1     U
2     O
3     U
```

U stands for used , O is open/UnUSED .

in my input I will get n as input number , which signifies the number of phones I want to reserve(update status to U from O )

I want a query that will lock(something like SELECT FOR UPDATE) the any **n available** row (rows that are **not locked yet** and having status as O )

Constraints: Table has millions of Used and unsed phones

**Updates for comments:**

problem is i Want **n (input) rows** to be locked with a particular status . i.e i have to work with rownum

I will be getting multiple concurrent calls in my service with sqli_n as input number of records to select :
so

```
SELECT * FROM PHONE_NUMBER WHERE STATUS='O' and rownum<=:sqli_n FOR UPDATE ;
```

this query wont work for me it will select only first n rows and if the first n rows are locked in 1 call the next/concurrent call will be stuck /wait until the first call updates the status to Used .

for update no wait will fail the above query

for update skip lock will also not work with row num

Comment: A simple `SELECT FOR UPDATE` wll do the trick. If you have millions of rows and want high performance you can use a filtered index.

Comment: What is wrong with `select for update`?

Comment: please see the update section in question for the things i have tried and why it is not working , the issue is ihave to work with rownum or something like that that will give me n rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this situation you need to use a for update cursor, because a `for update` clause is evaluated after the `where`:

> ```
> | PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                    |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | EXPLAINED SQL STATEMENT:                                                                             |
> | ------------------------                                                                             |
> | select /*+gather_plan_statistics*/ * from t where   decode(status, 'O',                              |
> | id) is not null   and rownum < 10 order by decode(status, 'O', id) asc                               |
> | for update skip locked                                                                               |
> |                                                                                                      |
> | Plan hash value: 2984481354                                                                          |
> |                                                                                                      |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | | Id  | Operation                     | Name     | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |          |      1 |        |      9 |00:00:00.01 |      21 | |
> | |   1 |  FOR UPDATE                   |          |      1 |        |      9 |00:00:00.01 |      21 | |
> | |*  2 |   COUNT STOPKEY               |          |      1 |        |      9 |00:00:00.01 |      10 | |
> | |   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T        |      1 |     49 |      9 |00:00:00.01 |      10 | |
> | |*  4 |     INDEX FULL SCAN           | IX_SFU_T |      1 |     10 |      9 |00:00:00.01 |       1 | |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> |                                                                                                      |
> | Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                  |
> | ---------------------------------------------------                                                  |
> |                                                                                                      |
> |    2 - filter(ROWNUM<10)                                                                             |
> |    4 - filter("T"."SYS_NC00005$" IS NOT NULL)                                                        |
> |                                                                                                      |
> ```

But for explicit cursor with `for update skip locked` you lock only fetched rows and no `rownum` evaluation exists in the query: you limit the number of locked rows with `limit` clause of fetch.

> ```
> create procedure l(s int)
> as
>   pragma autonomous_transaction;
>   type t_tab is table of t%rowtype
>     index by pls_integer;
>   t_data t_tab;
>   i pls_integer;
>   
>   cursor c is
>   select *
>   from t
>   where
>     decode(status, 'O', id) is not null
>   order by decode(status, 'O', id) asc
>   for update
>   skip locked;
> begin
>   
>   open c;
>   fetch c
>     bulk collect into t_data
>     limit 5
>   ;
>   /*Do stuff*/
>   commit;
>   close c;
> end;
> /
> ```

Additionally, to improve the query performance you can use index on expression that evaluates to null on the cases out of interest (where status != 'O' in your case). In the upper query I've used `decode`with the `id` column as output to assign rows in some predefined order (to use ordering on the same expression that was indexed to avoid table sorting), but if you do not need any order, index expression can be `decode(status, 'O', status)`.

Full setup is below. *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4aea29b48ffcf75fb7fae66920a47288)*

> ```
> create table t
> as
> select level as id,
>   dbms_random.string('x', 10)
>    as val,
>   dbms_random.random() as q,
>   decode(mod(level, 20), 0, 'O', 'U')
>     as status
> from dual
> connect by level < 1000
> ```

> ```
> /*We will use this expression
> for filtering and sorting*/
> create index ix_sfu_t
> on t(decode(status, 'O', id))
> ```

> ```
> begin
> dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(
>   sys_context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_SCHEMA'),
>   'T',
>   cascade => true
> );
> end;
> /
> ```

> ```
> select /*+gather_plan_statistics*/ *
> from t
> where
>   decode(status, 'O', id) is not null
>   and rownum < 5
> order by decode(status, 'O', id) asc
> for update
> skip locked
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | VAL        |           Q | STATUS
> -: | :--------- | ----------: | :-----
> 20 | 8XS78B92M2 |  1263442844 | O     
> 40 | XLLUN9DLV4 |  -435709224 | O     
> 60 | 2DZ4EUH11J | -1328077826 | O     
> 80 | PJKQMOBISR |  -644473876 | O
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from table(
>   dbms_xplan.display_cursor(
>   format => 'BASIC +PREDICATE +ALLSTATS LAST'
>   ))
> ```
>
> ```
> | PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                    |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | EXPLAINED SQL STATEMENT:                                                                             |
> | ------------------------                                                                             |
> | select /*+gather_plan_statistics*/ * from t where   decode(status, 'O',                              |
> | id) is not null   and rownum < 5 order by decode(status, 'O', id) asc                                |
> | for update skip locked                                                                               |
> |                                                                                                      |
> | Plan hash value: 2984481354                                                                          |
> |                                                                                                      |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | | Id  | Operation                     | Name     | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |          |      1 |        |      4 |00:00:00.01 |       8 | |
> | |   1 |  FOR UPDATE                   |          |      1 |        |      4 |00:00:00.01 |       8 | |
> | |*  2 |   COUNT STOPKEY               |          |      1 |        |      4 |00:00:00.01 |       2 | |
> | |   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T        |      1 |      4 |      4 |00:00:00.01 |       2 | |
> | |*  4 |     INDEX FULL SCAN           | IX_SFU_T |      1 |        |      4 |00:00:00.01 |       1 | |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> |                                                                                                      |
> | Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                  |
> | ---------------------------------------------------                                                  |
> |                                                                                                      |
> |    2 - filter(ROWNUM<5)                                                                              |
> |    4 - filter("T"."SYS_NC00005$" IS NOT NULL)                                                        |
> |                                                                                                      |
> ```

> ```
> /*To show which rows were locked*/
> create table t_log(
>   s_id int,
>   id int
> )
> ```

> ```
> create procedure l(s int)
> as
>   pragma autonomous_transaction;
>   type t_tab is table of t%rowtype
>     index by pls_integer;
>   t_data t_tab;
>   i pls_integer;
>   
>   /*Lock will be applied
>   to result set only*/
>   cursor c is
>   select *
>   from t
>   where
>     decode(status, 'O', id) is not null
>   order by decode(status, 'O', id) asc
>   for update
>   skip locked;
>
> begin
>   
>   open c;
>   fetch c
>     bulk collect into t_data
>     /*Will fetch 5 not locked rows*/
>     limit 5
>   ;
>   
>   /*Step into recursion
>   to demonstrate concurrent locking*/
>   if s > 0 then
>     l(s-1);
>   end if;
>   
>   forall i in 1..t_data.count
>     insert into t_log(s_id, id)
>       values(s, t_data(i).id);
>   commit;
>   close c;
> end;
> /
> ```

> ```
> begin
>   l(3);
> end;
> /
> ```

> ```
> /*Observe results*/
> select *
> from t_log;
> ```
>
> S_ID |  ID
> ---: | --:
>    0 | 320
>    0 | 340
>    0 | 360
>    0 | 380
>    0 | 400
>    1 | 220
>    1 | 240
>    1 | 260
>    1 | 280
>    1 | 300
>    2 | 120
>    2 | 140
>    2 | 160
>    2 | 180
>    2 | 200
>    3 |  20
>    3 |  40
>    3 |  60
>    3 |  80
>    3 | 100