# DBMS_LOCK usage in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle

We are using Oracle19c and have below code written in PL/SQL. Application is written in java 8.

```
HANDLE:=randomNum;
DBMS_LOCK.ALLOCATE_UNIQUE( 'LOCK5', HANDLE );
STATUS := DBMS_LOCK.REQUEST( LOCKHANDLE => HANDLE, LOCKMODE =>DBMS_LOCK.X_MODE );           

SELECT TR into P_NUMBER from T_MONITORING where PROCESS_S=0 and ROWNUM=1;
UPDATE T_MONITORING td set td.PROCESS_S=1 where td.TR=P_NUMBER and td.PROCESS_S =0;

NEW_TELEPHONE_NUMBER :=PHONE_NUMBER;
STATUS := DBMS_LOCK.RELEASE(LOCKHANDLE => HANDLE);
```

Table T_MONITORING contains 10 million records and multiple threads are calling this stored procedure. Objective is to process every record in this table. This procedure returns P_NUMBER and threads do some business logic and update this table (not shown here as it is a different stored procedure).

I would like to understand locking mechanism written in the pl/sql. I googled it but couldnt clearly understand it.
Does this code make sure that multiple threads calling this stored procedure wont get same `P_NUMBER`  ?

Please help in understand it.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not provide a timeout to wait when calling [`DBMS_LOCK.REQUEST`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_LOCK.html#GUID-CC3AEC00-CBFF-45DD-99C3-C7A312C0213E), it will use `MAXWAIT` default value. This value is described in the same page and has the following semantics:

> `maxwait  constant integer := 32767;`
>
> The constant maxwait waits forever.

So as long as the lock is requested in `X` mode (Exclusive), all other sessions will not execute all the below code (including `select` and `update`) unless the lock will be released. They will not get any value of `P_NUMBER` in the output.

When the lock is released in a correct way (not by timeout), processed rows will have `PROCESS_S=1` and will not fulfill `where` predicate of `select` statement: `where PROCESS_S=0 and ROWNUM=1;`

But if (for some reason) the lock will expire between `select` and `update`, it may provide the same `P_NUMBER` to different sessions of the application. It may be handled by `select ... for update skip locked`, that will not expire if the session is active.

Comment: Thanks astentx. I am able to understand your point but still have doubt. Can you modify the pl/sql i have mentioned with your understanding ? It will help me to understand better. Also, is it fine to have this lock mechanism in production system considering performance ?

Comment: @vjs Unfortunately, I don't have much experience in highly concurrent environment, but it looks ok. You need to have some sort of locking, and as long as there's no timeout specified, it will wait until some transaction will end processing or disconnect. My answer may be confusing, but I've missed that the lock is requested without timeout. Possibly, this may also be done via special mechanisms for queueing (for example, by using [AQ](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adque/)).

Comment: astentx : I have seen your answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67592561/lock-and-get-next-n-records-from-table-in-oracle?rq=1
I need similar requirement where multiple threads are fetching record from same table but there is no where clause means we have to process all the all records from the table...how can i connect with you ?